# "Unresolved reference: MediaSessionCompat" error when using "import androidx.media.session.MediaSessionCompat"

Tags: android, kotlin, media-player, androidx

I am trying to use MediaSessionCompat in my Kotlin code so I have this line in my source code:

```
import androidx.media.session.MediaSessionCompat
```

and this line in my "Module :app" "build.gradle" file:

```
implementation 'androidx.media:media:1.6.0'
```

as Google says to do here: [https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/media#declaring_dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com)

When I try to build, I get this error:

```
MainActivity.kt: (15, 31): Unresolved reference: MediaSessionCompat
```

Please can someone assist with this error? My Android Studio is up to date and I have done Gradle Sync.

Summary: I am unable to build a project using MediaSessionCompat

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'` dependency